# Flex grammar produces error: scanner push-back overflow

Tags: c++, c, lex, flex-lexer

I'm working with a grammar which uses off-sided parsing (iow: Tabs as block delimiters). The grammar uses an indent stack to keep track of nested blocks, and attempts to wrap blocks with appropriate closing tokens when EOF is encountered.

```
std::stack<int> indent_stack;
int indent_size;

%x indent
%s normal
%s wrap

%%

<wrap>[ ]       {
                    if(indent_stack.top() > 0)
                    {
                        indent_stack.pop();
                        if(indent_stack.top() > 0) unput(' ');
                        return DEDENT;
                    }
                    else
                        yyterminate();
                }

<<EOF>>         { 
                    if(indent_stack.top() > 0)
                    {
                        BEGIN(wrap);
                        unput(' ');
                    }
                    else
                        yyterminate();
                }

<indent>[\t]    {indent_size++;}
<indent>[\n]    {indent_size = 0;}

<indent>.       {
                    unput(*yytext);
                    if(indent_size > indent_stack.top())
                    {
                        indent_stack.push(indent_size);
                        yytext[0] = '\0';
                        return INDENT;
                    }
                    else if(indent_size < indent_stack.top())
                    {
                        indent_stack.pop();
                        yytext[0] = '\0';
                        return DEDENT;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BEGIN(normal);
                    }
                }
/* And so begin <normal> rules. */
```

At first glance, this grammar *appears* to work when lexing an input file: `yyin = fopen(...)`.

However when I attempt to lex an input string: `state = yy_scan_string(...)`, the first call to `yylex` crashes out with an error `flex scanner push-back overflow`.

Comment: I assume what you're asking is "how do I do what I want without it failing?", which I don't know the answer to. But if you're asking what the error means, it's in the Flex manual. "‘flex scanner push-back overflow’: you used unput() to push back so much text that the scanner's buffer could not hold both the pushed-back text and the current token in yytext. Ideally the scanner should dynamically resize the buffer in this case, but at present it does not."

Comment: This might happen if you grammar has left recursion

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say without the code, but my intuition points to the 
`<<EOF>>` rule: 
when

```
(indent_stack.top() > 0)
```

You are `unput`-ing in a infinite cycle: `EOF` stays always true, and BEGIN(wrap) (wrap is a inclusive start condition with no `<<EOF>>`) appears to be doing nothing in that context.

Is is very easy to have infinite cycles in `<<EOF>>` rules when we have
branches with no clauses of yyterminate, yyaccept, return or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Flex stores its input stream in a statically sized buffer. This error appears when you attempt to push too many characters back onto the stream and there isn't enough space left to hold them.

If you can statically bound the maximum number of characters that you think you'll ever push back into the buffer (maybe an MB?) you can override the size of the buffer by adding the following to the top of your .ll file. It's a hack, but for lack of dynamic memory management inside flex, it should work.

```
%{
  // Undefine the constant that flex uses when allocating its buffer
  #undef YY_BUF_SIZE

  // Pick some large constant. 
  // In my version flex 2.5.35 Apple(flex-31) the default is 16384
  #define YY_BUF_SIZE 1024*1024
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@Malcolm Rowe wrote:

> I assume what you're asking is "how do I do what I want without it failing?", which I don't know the answer to. But if you're asking what the error means, it's in the Flex manual. "‘flex scanner push-back overflow’: you used unput() to push back so much text that the scanner's buffer could not hold both the pushed-back text and the current token in yytext. Ideally the scanner should dynamically resize the buffer in this case, but at present it does not."

As you are running into system restrictions, I suspect this is as good an answer as can be made at this point.

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have a recursive definition of any token in your Lex file.The error simply suggest that lex inbuilt buffer is not able to hold the tokens expressions.
Are you getting the error while compiling your parser ?

Comment: No it doesn't. See @MalcolmRowe's comment.

Comment: yes ,i gave you one of the possibility.The comment you are talking about is absolutely correct but is just a explanation not the solution.This is what i used to resolve my problem.I understand,there could be number of reason for not allocating the buffer automatically.